# Call from detective

Tags: criminal-law, theft, pennsylvania, fifth-amendment

say hypothetically someone committed a the crime of stealing a public sign and being publicly intoxicated under the age of 21..

The next day a detective calls asking to talk in person and says they "are not going to get arrested"

What should the person do?

Show up alone?

Show up with a lawyer?

Show up but don't say anything and then ask to speak with a lawyer?

Don't show up at all?

This is all hypothetically in the united states in Pennsylvania

Comment: Does not sound very hypothetical to me. Show up with a lawyer.

Comment: Rephrase this to ask whether or not police can compel you to come to the station for an interview and I would vote to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

#### You don't have to talk to the police.

All taking a lawyer with you will do is have someone to remind you not to talk to the police, and short your bank account a couple hundred dollars.

Tell the detective you're busy.  The detective saying you "are not going to be arrested" means absolutely nothing.  When they show up to talk to you, don't go to the door unless they have a warrant.